# how to move whole text down in jsp?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have made a menu bar at the top of my page.
But when I insert the main body, it just overlaps with my menu bar rectangle. How do I move my whole body text down to avoid overlapping?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
    div.ex
    {
        width:300px;
        padding:10px;
        border:5px solid gray;
        background: white;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top: 200px;
        position: relative;
    }
    p.x {
        color: white;
        font:25px arial,sans-serif;
        position:relative;
        left:20px;
    }
    .align {
        position: absolute;
        left: 8em;
    }
    body
    {
        background-color: #ebebeb;
        top: 55px;
    }
    #rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        background: deepskyblue;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 20;
    }
    input[type=button]
    {
        background-color: lawngreen;
        color: white;
    }
</Style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rectangle">
<p class="x">Home Page <a href="personal?id=${id}"><input type="button" name="sign up"   value="Sign Up"/></a></p>
</div>
<h1>Hello world, this is your home page.</h1>
<div class="ex">
<h1>签订</h1>
<hr>
${errorMessage}
<form action="register" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            ID：
            <input type="text" name="id" value="${person.id}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            密码：
            <input type="password" name="password" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            确认密码：
            <input type="password" name="password" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            姓名：
            <input type="text" name="name" value="${person.name}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            地址：
            <input type="text" name="address" value="${person.address}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            电话：
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="${person.phoneNumber}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="注册"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The sentence of "Hello world, this is your home page." has been overlapped with blue rectangle I made. I want to move whole body field down. I know one method would be putting bunch of 
, but there must be other ways to do the same thing.

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your CSS for that. For example, by padding your top with 60px like so:

```
#rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        background: deepskyblue;
        position: fixed;
        top: 60px;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 20;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this looks odd since th would place "Hello world, this is your home page." above the menu bar!

Comment: @user3014926 If u want "Hello world, this is your home page." below the menu bar then u have to change the CSS of h1 tag, if my answer works for u please mark it as correct, so it will be helpful for others my friend

Comment: Thank you. This helps and it looks like you just need to add padding-top for h1.

Comment: @user3014926 yes, so please click on my answer so it will be helpful for others

Comment: @user3014926 please upvote it or mark it as correct, so it will be helpful for u and stackoverflow as well

Comment: @user3014926 what happened I have helped you and you are not upvoting it

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to stackoverflow, so I am trying to figure out all functions!

Comment: @user3014926 you have to simple fill the right mark my friend which came on the left side of my post by simply clicking on it

Answer (score 0):

check this [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2xRA/32/)

use

```
 #rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        background: deepskyblue;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 20;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add padding-top:50px; to the body tag

```
body {
   padding-top: 50px
}
```